# Setting common base class properties when creating objects

Tags: c#

what would be the best way to eliminate the repeated code to set the base class properties while creating the objects? please see the code below

```
public class  Employee
{
     public string DailyWorkHours { get; set; }
     public string WeeklyHolidays { get; set; }
}

public class ContractEmployee : Employee
{ 
      public string ContractDuration {get; set;}
}

public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{
     public string MonthlySalary {get; set; }
}

public class ContractEmployyeBuilder
{
   public void BuildObject ()
   {
        ContractEmployee emp = new ContractEmployee();
        emp.DailyWorkHours   = "8hours";
        emp.WeeklyHolidays  = "saturday and Sunday" ;
        emp.ContractDuration = "1 month" ;
   } 
}

public class FullTimeEmployeeBuilder
{
     public void BuildObject()
     {
          FullTimeEmployee emp = new FullTimeEmployee();
          emp.DailyWorkHours   = "8hours";
          emp.WeeklyHolidays   = "saturday and Sunday" ;
          emp.MonthlySalary    = "£2500";
     } 
}
```

As you can see from the code above, the BuildObject method of the ContractEmployyeBuilder and FullTimeEmployeeBuilder classes are responsible for creating the respective objects and populate their properties.

The two properties which belongs to the base class and will always have the same values. both the builder classes has repeated code to do this job.

How can we restructure these Builder classes  in such a  way that we can get rid of the repeated code to set the base class properties?

Answer (score 1):

### What about a full hierarchical and polymorphic solution? Object-oriented programming goodness!

Each inheritance level can call base EmployeeBuilder implementation directly! *This is the elegant solution*:

```
// Thanks to the generics power, each builder derived class
// will must provide the employee type to build, and it must be
// Employee or a derived of Employee class.
public class EmployeeBuilder<TEmployee>
    where TEmployee : Employee, new ()
{
    public virtual void BuildObject(TEmployee employee = null)
    {
        // If an instance is given as argument ok, if not 
        // one is created from scratch!
        TEmployee emp = employee ?? new TEmployee();
        emp.DailyWorkHours = "8hours";
        emp.WeeklyHolidays = "saturday and Sunday";
    }
}

public class ContractEmployeeBuilder<TEmployee> : EmployeeBuilder<TEmployee> where TEmployee : ContractEmployee, new ()
{
    public override void BuildObject(TEmployee employee = null)
    {
        // If an instance is given as argument ok, if not 
        // one is created from scratch!
        TEmployee emp = employee ?? new TEmployee();
        emp.ContractDuration = "1 month";
        base.BuildObject(emp);
    }
}

public class FullTimeEmployeeBuilder<TEmployee> : EmployeeBuilder<TEmployee> where TEmployee : FullTimeEmployee, new ()
{
    public override void BuildObject(TEmployee employee = null)
    {
        // If an instance is given as argument ok, if not 
        // one is created from scratch!
        TEmployee emp = employee ?? new TEmployee();
        emp.MonthlySalary = "£2500";
        base.BuildObject(emp);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2996309 have you checked the last update with the full inheritance + polymorphism approach?

Comment: @user2996309 I've removed the first approach. I believe you should go with the full inheritance + polymoprhism with generics approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have a constructor in the `base` class that sets the common values:

```
public Employee()
{
    DailyWorkHours = "8hours";
    WeeklyHolidays = "saturday and Sunday";
}
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UGODsD)

Or as you mentioned in comments you want the values to be set in the builder, you'd need a constructor in the base which takes the parameters:

```
public Employee(string dailyWorkHours, string weeklyHolidays)
{
    DailyWorkHours = dailyWorkHours;
    WeeklyHolidays = weeklyHolidays;
}
```

Then your constructors in your derived classes can take said parameters and then call the base constructor:

```
public ContractEmployee (string dailyWorkHours, string weeklyHolidays) 
    : base(string dailyWorkHours, string weeklyHolidays)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already thought about that. But, I do not want the Employee class to to populate its properties. the value of these properties might come from a database or another service. So I would like the Builder class to be responsible to populate all the fields.

Comment: @user2996309 Then you can create constructors for each type that pass in the values as parameters, which in turn calls a base constructor that takes the parameters and sets them.

Comment: BTW it seems like OP wants to use *factory pattern*

Comment: @user2996309 you need the overloads for your constructors, in your builders or employee class, or you will end with a bunch duplicated code, there is no difference if it comes from database or UI controls or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following?

```
public class EmployeeBuilder
{
    public ContractEmployee BuildContractEmployee()
    {
        var emp = Create<ContractEmployee>();

        emp.ContractDuration = "1 month";

        return emp;
    }

    public FullTimeEmployee BuildFullTimeEmployee()
    {
        var emp = Create<FullTimeEmployee>();

        emp.MonthlySalary = "£2500";

        return emp;
    }

    private static T Create<T>() where T : Employee, new()
    {
        return new T {DailyWorkHours = "8hours", WeeklyHolidays = "saturday and Sunday"};
    }
}
```